# Templating issues with Backbone.js views : this.el attributes

Tags: view, rendering, backbone.js, jquery-templates

I'm trying to find the best way to render a li-element :

I've read that i should **never** replace `this.el`

So it seems that i have to unwrap my template in my `LiView` `render()` function :

```
// replace element content with html generated from template
var $rendered = $.tmpl(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
this.el.html($rendered.unwrap().html());
```

I just get the contents inside the `$rendered` li, since i should not replace it.

But how should i transfer attributes ?

I tried :

```
this.el.attr('class', $rendered.attr('class'));
this.el.attr('title', $rendered.attr('title'));
```

But it replaces attributes... And some (like jQuery ui ui-draggable) could be lost.

All this seems a bit clunky...

Thanks !

Comment: I'm curious where you've read that you should never replace `this.el`.  It seems sensical not to change it, but I've had to do it for the exact reason you've outlined here.  It's too bad that you can't instantiate a view with a template obj.  Anyways, replacing `this.el` in practice works fairly well (even though it feels pretty dirty) just so long as you call `this.delegateEvents` after doing it.

Comment: @idbentley - if I reassign el my events are broken even when calling this.delegateEvents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully grasp what you're trying to do Olouv, but I'll have a stab at answering your question regardless :)

You have an liView that corresponds to an li dom element
So you need to specify

```
el: "li"
```

Do not have an li in your template. Then the result of your render will be

```
<li>
    contents of template
</li>
```

Now you want to add attributes to this li element?
Class names are pretty simple, just add the className attribute to your view

```
className: "ui-draggable myGreatClass ui-corner-all"
```

If you need to add additional attributes to your root (li) element

```
$(el).attr("title","your title")
```

If that doesn't work for you, and you want to put the li attributes in your template perhaps consider some form of the following:

1. Tolerating HTML of the form:
2. Instead of an liView  (list item view), just have a ulView (List view), and put a loop construct in your template